# C# Application Relative Paths

Tags: c#, path, streamreader, streamwriter

I just started learning C# and it looks like when you are writing an output file or reading an input file, you need to provide the absolute path such as follows:

```
        string[] words = { "Hello", "World", "to", "a", "file", "test" };
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\jackf_000\Projects\C#\First\First\output.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(word);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
```

MSDN's examples make it look like you need to provide the absolute directory when instantiating a StreamWriter:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

I have written in both C++ and Python and you do not need to provide the absolute directory when accessing files in those languages, just the path from the executable/script. It seems like an inconvenience to have to specify an absolute path every time you want to read or write a file.

Is there any quick way to grab the current directory and convert it to a string, combining it with the outfile string name? And is it good style to use the absolute directory or is it preferred to, if it's possible, quickly combine it with the "current directory" string?

Thanks.

Comment: [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) and [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) -- and no you don't have to specify the full path. Relative paths work in C#, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to specify full directory everytime, relative directory also work for C#, you can get current directory using following way-

Gets the current working directory of the application.

```
string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Gets or sets the fully qualified path of the current working directory.

```
string directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Get program executable path

```
string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

[Resource Link 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)  [Resource Link 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

defiantly, you no need specify full path , what is the good way you perform this type of criteria?

should use relative path @p.s.w.g mention already by comment to use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` and `Path.Combine`

some more specify by flowing way

You can get the `.exe` location of your app with `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.`

```
string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string exeDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
DirectoryInfo binDir = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(exeDir);
```

on the other hand 
Internally, when getting `Environment.CurrentDirectory` it will call `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` and when setting `Environment.CurrentDirectory` it will call `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`.

Just pick a favorite and go with it.

thank you welcome C# i hope it will  help you  to move forward