# Self Contained EXE not finding correct path on OS X

Tags: c#, json, path, exe, csproj

So I've made a self-contained release of a project with Visual Studio Code. The EXE is working on ubuntu and windows, but can't get it to work on os-x.

I'm using a simple `data.json` to store some data. The error that occurs on the os-x release, is that it can't find the correct path to `data.json`. I get this message:

```
Could not find file '/Users/User/data.json'.
```

That is not where I store the release or data.json. I store it in the root-directory of the project. Seems like the application is looking for the json-file in my system root directories. How do I fix this?

My XML csproj:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The csproj is almost never useful. The part of your code that opens the file, on the other hand, almost certainly contains your issue.

Comment: @zneak I just have a static reference to the source:
private static string _source = "data.json";
Which is used to read and write to the file

Comment: Wondering if my local file data.json should be declared in a "PackageReference"...

Comment: No, PackageReference is for libraries. Just using "data.json" makes the path relative to the application's current working directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041658/c-sharp-application-relative-paths

Comment: Also, from where do you run the generated executable? if you open a new terminal, the working directory is your user directory and if you call `./path/to/app` it will look in that directory for any relative paths since it is the current working directory